# what's different data and dataa property in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, properties, access-modifiers

what's different between the two?

```
fun main(){
class A<T>(name : T){
    val dataa : T = name     // <-- no problem using private modifier or not
    fun getData() : T = dataa
}

class B<T>(name : T){
    val data : T = name
    //^^^ i get the error and i have to use private modifier or use the @JvmField
    fun getData() : T = data
   }
}
```

what is the difference between `val data` and `val dataa` ?

is `data` the default property in kotlin ?

Comment: `public getData()` and `public setData()` are auto-generated by compiler... To edit getData(), use `val data: T = name get() = field` instead

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a keyword in Kotlin (like `class`, `fun`,…) so you can't use it as an identifier.

(The StackOverflow code highlighter makes that clear: in the question, you can see that `data` is in blue, like `val`.)

If you really need to call your property ‘data’, you can surround it in backticks everywhere you use it.  But it's almost always better to pick another name.

Also, as Animesh pointed out in a comment, you don't need to define a getter method; Kotlin generates one automatically for every (non-private) property.  You can override it if you need to, but the syntax for that is different.